# Custom shape in Visio for workflows

Tags: workflow

I am trying to find a guide or tutorial to create custom Visio shapes for use in Visio created workflows. Can someone guide me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shape Studio is availabe with the Visio SDK for Visio 2003 and Visio 2007, but was removed for Visio 2010.  I have not used Visio 2010, so I don't know for certian what has replaced it, but the integration with VS 2010 is improved so it may have been moved there.

[Visio 2003 SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=557120bd-b0bb-46e7-936a-b8539898d44d&displaylang=en)

[Visio 2007 SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=373D34B8-5EF7-4E6E-A582-C8D6B5EE4E33&displaylang=en)

Answer (score 0):

Actually ShapeStudio is removed from Visio 2010 SDK and is NOT replaced with anything. Naugthy Microsoft!